# Calculating the area of irregular shape in R

Tags: r, area, curve

I would like to calculate the closed area in R as in the graph below:
[image: example_1]

The code is:

```
a <- c(0,1,2,2,1,0,-1,-2,-2,-1,0)
b <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
id <- order(a)
AUC <- sum(abs(diff(a[id])*rollmean(b[id],2)))
```

The result for AUC is 0.5. Why it is not 1?

When I do the same, but for different vectors, second example:
[image]
The code is:

```
a <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
b <- c(1,1,2,1,0,-1,-1,-2,-1,0,1) 
id <- order(a) 
AUC <- sum(abs(diff(a[id])*rollmean(b[id],2)))
```

The result is 1, which I have expected.

And the final, most important question is:
I have 2 columns x and y in dataframe(100 rows, 2 columns) which form closed curve of irregular shape (cyclogram) when plotted x versus y, Like in this picture:
[image]
I want to calculate area of that shape using 2 columns x and y. Is there a way of doing this?

**updated:**
Data for the 3rd example (cyclogram) is:

```
structure(c(-0.317857301365341, -0.27254852000745, -0.239116190750992, 
-0.212617899743053, -0.188665601384051, -0.164652457277714, -0.516811363687365, 
-0.704142203990645, -0.925833008271225, -1.17644987082148, -1.44698060870818, 
-1.72501192276032, -1.99567842934217, -2.24329812421979, -2.45336219338653, 
-2.61434899714043, -2.71894439436842, -2.76453987881648, -2.75307392975534, 
-2.69034804478649, -2.58498022688992, -2.44717942836848, -2.28751639917794, 
-2.11583498227994, -1.94040889261091, -1.76740411983085, -1.37034128566268, 
-0.945317248194438, -0.603583991912112, -0.245876237842544, 0.12405281597095, 
0.500705070183803, 1.07928003293753, 1.3786192588209, 1.93625569819096, 
2.32102987210859, 2.67667485884349, 2.9817217810439, 3.21508203608072, 
3.35805065942255, 3.39629843099713, 3.32158207702952, 3.13297595252244, 
2.83749468084523, 2.44998880428773, 1.99219777869042, 1.34133852767483, 
0.905097245217795, 0.332495432968877, 0.000565676359279427, -0.304679355313777, 
-0.676576930379378, -0.799504493858939, -0.877037748519715, -0.907917643885644, 
-0.895574022744618, -0.847333419315191, -0.773304922267926, -0.68506594358595, 
-0.594261154658402, -0.511242949335073, -0.443908244418344, -0.396899995824444, 
-0.371311027504522, -2.95318107124334, -2.91494448796198, -2.80017869044755, 
-2.61894793180667, -2.38576761259564, -2.11805651326137, -1.41368736155233, 
-0.896608829738209, -0.363137342157785, 0.165324041578864, 0.668413502524084, 
1.12765173596156, 1.52716559439287, 1.85443533430032, 2.10104197466128, 
2.26318484127474, 2.34177274880676, 2.34207035998987, 2.2729829455437, 
2.14607786936849, 1.97445291610407, 1.77157880225516, 1.5502403566333, 
1.32167995293426, 1.09501806084454, 0.876985405337858, 0.780951474855999, 
0.715653776169357, 0.631076472349792, 0.572023400386015, 0.534441560957589, 
0.513328184556074, 0.275997813967411, 0.34478353180991, 0.504249489908016, 
0.587434743269948, 0.654235885315243, 0.701450060739606, 0.72746455454756, 
0.732567090012129, 0.718940924224628, 0.690264488986728, 0.650927827300914, 
0.604983707715769, 0.555050419060634, 0.501440460475964, 0.370959009632643, 
0.337726723524854, 0.216270960220213, 0.162458598954556, 0.060364386887637, 
-0.136702597984821, -0.309488796931729, -0.535968167790145, -0.807754519418657, 
-1.11285625385781, -1.43643730574278, -1.76172554792592, -2.0710195962479, 
-2.34678141009815, -2.57280751486803, -2.73543188753935, -2.82464965255479, 
-2.83501170706251), .Dim = c(64L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("309", 
"310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", 
"319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", 
"328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", "336", 
"337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", "345", 
"346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", "353", "354", 
"355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", "363", 
"364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", "372"
), c("PC1", "PC2")))
```

Comment: See my answer below. I you provide the points of the cyclogram we can test it!

Comment: Hi Waldi, thank you for the answer! I have provided the points of cyclogram in the <updated> part of the post.

Comment: See my edit with cyclogram's approximation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what is the method you used and why it didn't work in this case.
An alternative is to use `sf` ([simple features](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/)), which handles area calculation :

```r
library(sf)  

a <- c(0,1,2,2,1,0,-1,-2,-2,-1,0)
b <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)

poly <- st_polygon(list(cbind(a,b)))
poly <- st_make_valid(poly)
plot(poly)
```

[image]

```r
st_area(poly)
#> [1] 1
```

Note the use of `st_make_valid` because **polygons should be non intersecting**, which is not the case in the three examples you provided.
In the first example, the polygon is transfomed in 2 polygons and 2 linestrings:

```
st_make_valid(poly)
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((-2 1, -1 0, -2 0, -2 1)), ((2 0, 1 0, 2 1, 2 0))), 
                    MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, -1 0), (0 0, 1 0)))
```

For the cyclogram, the intersection points of the trajectory are needed if you want an exact area, which is not the case in the data you provided.
As an approximation, you could use `concaveman`:

```
library(concaveman)
st_polygon(list(concaveman(data)))

plot(st_polygon(list(concaveman(data))), col='grey')
plot(st_linestring(data),add=T,col='red')

st_area(st_polygon(list(concaveman(data))))
[1] 2.693168
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! And do you maybe know how to calculate area if coordinates (x,y) of intersection points are given?

Comment: Each loop needs to be closed for `st_make_valid(poly)` to work, so that you can calculate the surface out of it.  In the trajectory, you need to insert the intersection point at the beginning and end of each loop.